# iOS Can't get my custom back button to show

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, back

I'm having trouble setting a custom back button.  Below is the current code I'm using in the parent ViewController in viewDidLoad:

```
UIButton *custBackButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[custBackButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:custBackButton];
```

I can get the below code to work as a test:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

Can anyone give me a pointer or two with what I'm doing wrong for the first example?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don not use self.navigationItem.backbarbutton....use self.navigationItem.leftbarbutton....it will work....and before that make self.backbarbutton=nil....to remove it, otherwise it will overlap...and this wont run ur custom button